# bash - parallel loop with pool of resources

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, locking, pool

I have a script that looks like this:

```
for x in ...; do
    for y in ...; do
        # run several commands which depends on x and y and requires a single GPU
        # (I also need to specify which GPU to use)
        command1 $x $y GPU0
        command2 $x $y GPU0
    done
done

# Some stuff after the loop
```

I have 4 GPUs. I want to make the loop parallel. I.e. for the current `(x,y)` iteration, I want to wait until some GPU is available, run the commands, and go to the next iteration (without waiting for the current iteration to finish). How do I do this?

I know about `flock` command, so I can create a lock file for each GPU and use it to control access to the GPU. But, as I understand, it requires me to know which GPU my current `(x,y)` iteration plans to use.

And another concern is how to guarantee that at every iteration I use correct `x` and `y`. I.e., when we go to the next iteration, `x` and `y` change, and it must not be reflected in `command1 $x $y GPU...` at the previous iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -j4 'echo Do {1} and {2} on GPU {%}; sleep 1.$RANDOM;' ::: a b c ::: X Y Z
```

To follow the progress use `--lb`:

```
parallel -j4 --lb 'echo Do {1} and {2} on GPU {%}; sleep 1.$RANDOM; echo GPU {%} done' ::: a b c ::: X Y Z
```

To use variable in the command you need to be aware of quoting and exporting the variable:

```
a='a  b  **  $  <  >'
export a
parallel 'echo "$a"' ::: test
```

For details see: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#quoting and https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example-using-shell-variables

If the content of the variable does not change when `eval`ed, you can get away with not quoting:

```
a=ab
parallel echo $a ::: test
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a (hopefully) quick question: if I have a variable, say `a=123`, how can I use it in the code (i.e. as `$a`). I see a workaround: just to add `::: $a` and to refer to it as `{3}`, but I wonder if I can use the variable by name.